# Invalid version string "1.1.0,,<2.0"

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php

I'm trying to install a [library](https://github.com/mihaylichenko/yii2-widget-mappicker) for the Yii framework 2, and get an error:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint >=1.1.0,,<2.0: Invalid version string "1.1.0,,<2.0"
```

I looked at the list of requirements in the *composer.json*, but there are no problems.

Comment: [composer.json](https://pastebin.com/g1ngt0ZT)

Comment: Maybe that invalid version string is in *your* composer.json…?

Comment: @deceze no, the versions are correct there, I attached a link to the _composer.json_ above

Comment: It probably comes from one of `npm-asset` dependencies - npm repository is a mess...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was much easier than I thought. I have a global [fxp/composer-asset-plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/fxp/composer-asset-plugin) installed. I just deleted it and problem was solved.